# How to conditionally format cells based on presence of strikethrough text?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to the cells in [this example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UN5MpCI41G5KkbrdXeLCvI7WGkKNVLyi7U2bsSXyBJk/edit?usp=sharing).

Currently, I have a list of clients that occasionally report issues in the corresponding month columns. Once the issue is reported, the cell changes color to red based on the conditional formatting rule: if cell is not empty -- background color -> red.

Once the issue has been addressed / fixed, strikethrough is applied to the cell by the user. I would like to be able to change the background color of the cell at this point to green to show visually that the issue is resolved and visually separate resolved issue cells from unresolved issue cells. In a perfect world the solution would be along the lines of: Format cells if -- cell contains 'strikethrough' -- apply background color -> green.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no function that does what you would like.

What do you think if instead of the strikethrough we distinguished the two cases with the variants of the verb: `is` and `was` ?

We could so easily get something like:
[image: is & was]